# Cycle through a list of terms and batch rename files

Tags: bash, perl, zsh

**EDIT**: In the course of working on and reediting this question, I was able to get this to work. However, I'm sure there's a better way to do it, so I'm leaving it up to hear from those more experienced.

Periodically I need to reproduce several dozen copies of a few files. For example, given:

```
company_a_results_30d.py
company_a_results_90d.py
company_a_results_120d.py
company_a_results_all_time.py
```

I need to make copies where `company_a` is replaced with `company_b`, `company_c`....etc. (The next step is to find and replace a number of terms within the files, but this I have managed to do with a perl script.)

I'm sure this should be possible with a bash script and `mv`, but I haven't quite got the hang of it. Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
my_array=(company_b company_c company_d)
for i in "${my_array[@]}" 
do
  for file in *.py
  do
    cp "$file" "${file/company_a/$i}"
  done
done
```

I'd prefer a solution compatible with `zsh`, which is what I use.

Comment: Josh, would you please post your solution as an answer?  For myself, I use  Aristotle's `rename` Perl script from http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=303814 for renaming.  `rename 's/company_a/company_b/' *.py` or the like.

Comment: Done, and thanks - I'll have a look! I'm partial to perl, from the little I've done with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### bash

Slightly modified from [the OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56481591/2877364):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x      # So you can see what's happening - feel free to omit

company_a_files=(company_a*.py)  # <== Save the list of files first

my_array=(company_b company_c company_d)
for i in "${my_array[@]}" 
do
  for file in "${company_a_files[@]}"    # <== Use the saved list
  do
    cp "$file" "${file/company_a/$i}"
  done
done
```

When the inner loop in the OP's answer runs `for file in *.py`, the glob will pick up whatever `company_b` &c. files have already been created.  So you wind up with a lot of `set -x` output like:

```
+ cp company_b_1.py company_b_1.py
cp: 'company_b_1.py' and 'company_b_1.py' are the same file
```

Instead, save the glob of company_a files into a shell array first, and then
loop over that array.

#### perl

As a one-liner for Perl 5.14+:

```
 perl -MFile::Copy=copy -E 'for my $file (@ARGV) { copy $file, $file =~ s/company_a/$_/r foreach qw(company_b company_c company_d) }' company_a*.py
```

The Perl version switches the loop order compared to the bash version.  For each file given on the command line (the `for ... @ARGV`), it copies from that file to each name-modified file in turn (the `foreach`).

`$file =~ s/company_a/$_/r` is a non-destructive (`/r`) replace in `$file` (the filename) that changes `company_a` to `$_` (the current value from `foreach`).

Comment: Thanks - the explanations and optimisations are really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution I came up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
my_array=(company_b company_c company_d)
for i in "${my_array[@]}" 
do
  for file in *.py
  do
    cp "$file" "${file/company_a/$i}"
  done
done
```

Comment: Looks good to me - I'm not sure it would be much shorter in Perl anyway :)